# If a table T1 has single column c1 with data base (a,a,b,b,b,c)

Tags: sql

If a table T1 has single column c1 with data base (a,a,b,b,b,c)
write a query that gives output as

```
a  2
b  3
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT c1, COUNT(*)
FROM T1
GROUP BY c1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    'a',
    2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'b',
    3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c1, count(*) FROM T1 GROUP BY c1 HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: yep i notices this after submitting answer, corected